# Advantage of asynchronous code on server side?

Tags: asynchronous, serverside-javascript

Suppose I have an API endpoint written in JavaScript such as Scenario A and Scenario B below (Note, this is pseudo code for illustration purposes).
The result of the database call, and the results of function A and function B need to be returned by the server at the same time.

**Note: my question is not about how asynchronous code works.**

Scenario A - asynchronous

```
db_connection.async_query(sql)
  .then( result => {
    functionA(result);
  })
  .then( result => {
    functionB(result);
  })
```

Scenario B - synchronous

```
const result = db_onnection.sync_query(sql)
functionA(result)
functionB(result)
```

Since the result of the database call and the result of both functions need to be returned by the server simultaneously, is there any benefit to the asynchronous version? It is less concise and not as easy to read as the synchronous version.

I have a fairly complex application with asynchronous code in the browser which makes perfect sense, but I wonder if it adds needless complexity to the server side since I am ultimately sending back the result of everything all at once anyway.

An exception I can think of is if I were to make an API call to enter a new user into the database and also send them an email. The email will not be part of the server response so asynchronous execution is better as they can run simultaneously.

What is the advantage to the asynchronous version of these two scenarios?